# Get information from a dictionary and set it in a cell in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

this is my first time using excel-vba and I am facing a little problem.
I have created a dictionary [key, value, value] and i want to set the value to diferents cells. By now i have done this:

```
Sub CodisFactura()

Fulla1 = Sheets("Ac2 i Factura").Select
Fulla1.Activate

'''''''''

primeraFactura = 5
ultimaFactura = 30

numeroFactura = 5
numColumnaProva = 15

'''''''''



Dim diccCodis As Object
Set diccCodis = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With diccCodis
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "1", Array("RX004", "Resta d'ecografies convencionals")
    .Add "2", Array("RA00414", "Ecografía  de cuello")
    .Add "3", Array("RA00415", "Ecografía de torax")


    Do While numeroFactura >= primeraFactura And numeroFactura < ultimaFactura

        Cells(numeroFactura, numColumnaProva).Value = codiSeleccionat

        keysDicc = diccCodis.Keys

        codiProva = keysDicc(codiSeleccionat)(0)
        nomProva = diccCodis.Item(codiSeleccionat)(1)

        Cells(numeroFactura, 7).Value = codiProva
        Cells(numeroFactura, 12).Value = nomProva

        numeroFactura = numeroFactura + 1

    Loop

    End With
```

I am having "error 13" at this two lines:

`codiProva = keysDicc(codiSeleccionat)(0)
nomProva = diccCodis.Item(codiSeleccionat)(1)`

which is a Type missmatch error: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-mismatch-error-13

how can I do it?
Am i doing something wrong in the whole code?

Comment: at the end of the file i have the end of the sub: End Sub

Comment: Declaring all of your variables would make it easier for me to follow your code (especially with language difficulties).  But what is `codiSeleccionat` and where does it get set to a value? It looks like it is undefined; so it is probably a variant data type that is empty.

Comment: Again, having your data and expected results would be helpful, but perhaps it should be `codiSeleccionat = Cells(numeroFactura, numColumnaProva).Value`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry for lenguajes difficulties, this is for my dad, who does not speak english. codiSeleccionat (selectedcode) are the keys. I want to put a number (key) in a cell, search that number in the dicctionary and "print" the 2 values in other cells.

Comment: Then you'll want to reverse the `codi = cellvalue` line as I indicated.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i have tried reversing the line but still having the same problem. I have tried to change the second line as the first one ` codiProva = keysDicc(codiSeleccionat)(0)
  nomProva = keysDicc(codiSeleccionat)(1) ` and the issue only appeards in the second one

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your code.

- `Cells(numeroFactura, numColumnaProva).Value = codiSeleccionat` is backwards.  You want `codiSeleccionat` to get the value from the cell, not the other way around as this states.
- `codiProva = keysDicc(codiSeleccionat)(0)` I suspect your object should be the Dictionary, and not the array of keys to the dictionary
- I suspect you are entering numbers into your worksheets cells, but when you create your dictionary, you are using strings.  `"1"` is not the same key as `1`

The code below shows one way of addressing those issues:

```
Dim diccCodis As Object
Set diccCodis = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With diccCodis
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    .Add 1, Array("RX004", "Resta d'ecografies convencionals")
    .Add 2, Array("RA00414", "Ecograf?a  de cuello")
    .Add 3, Array("RA00415", "Ecograf?a de torax")


    Do While numeroFactura >= primeraFactura And numeroFactura < ultimaFactura

        codiSeleccionat = Cells(numeroFactura, numColumnaProva).Value

        keysDicc = diccCodis.Keys

        codiProva = diccCodis(codiSeleccionat)(0)
        nomProva = diccCodis.Item(codiSeleccionat)(1)

        Cells(numeroFactura, 7).Value = codiProva
        Cells(numeroFactura, 12).Value = nomProva

        numeroFactura = numeroFactura + 1

    Loop

    End With
```

You'll be better off always declaring all of your variables.  It can catch errors and possibly make things less confusing. I don't understand why MS makes NOT requiring variable declaration the default. Select `Tools/Options/Editor` and check `Require Variable Declaration`.  This will place `Option Explicit` at the start of any new module.  To correct **this** module, enter it manually at the beginning.

Given your code, below is a screenshot of the results.
Of course, your code does not do any error checking for blanks or bad entries in column `O`, and you should add code to handle that, else it will stop ungraciously.

[image]